Expression evaluation in printf with %p
I am studying pointers in C. Trying a bunch of things to make sure I understand how pointers work, I found something that I don't understand. Here's the snippet of the code in question:
int b = 30;
printf("(void *)(size_t)b: %p\n", (void *)(size_t)b);

Output:
(void *)(size_t)b: 0x1e

That is the value 30, stored at "b", in hexadecimal. I have put the expression inside so I know which one is which in the console.
I am compiling the code with GCC 13.2.1-6 and the flags
-Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=c17 -pedantic-errors
in a x86-64 Linux machine. I don't know if it's relevant (I'm a beginner) but an int has 4 bytes for me.
The code compiles fine with no errors. I couldn't understand why it gives that output.

There's no guarantee that it will.  That having been said, that is the most likely result.  b has the value 30, which in hex is 0x1e.  The cast to size_t doesn't change that.  The cast to void * simply creates a pointer from that value, which on your platform, and with the value 30, preserves that value as a pointer.  So you ended up with a void * pointer with the value 30, or 0x1e.  What did you expect it to do?

I was expecting an error, because I am using "b" instead of "&b"

If you assigned it to a pointer, rather than casting it, then you would have gotten a warning at least.  But if you cast an integer to a pointer, you generally won't get a warning.

int b = 30;

You now have an int value of 30 (0x1e).
(size_t)b

You tell the compiler to treat this as a size_t value of 30 (0x1e).
(void *)(size_t)b

You tell the compiler to treat this size_t value of 30 (0x1e) as a void *.
printf("%p", (void *)(size_t)b);

You print the value of the pointer, which is 30 (0x1e). Note that %p prints the pointer, not what the pointer points to.
And you mustn't dereference that pointer (by adding an asterisk in front of (void *)(size_t)b), because your pointer isn't valid, i.e. it does not actually point to something, so dereferencing it would be undefined behavior (i.e., bad).
If you want to print the address of b, you need to take that address, using the address operator &:
int b = 30;
printf("%p", (void *)&b);


The expression (void *)(size_t)b is already undefined behaviour in Standard C, unless there happens to exist a valid object at that address.  Specific platforms might define the behaviour

@M.M As far as I understand, casting an integer to void * is not undefined behavior. (We would get into trouble with #define NULL (void *)0 if it were.) If I am wrong, I'd be interested in which part of the standard you take that claim from.

The UB is evaluating the result of the expression . A pointer value must point to a valid object , or null, when evaluated  (note: I intentionally say "evaluated", not "dereferenced")

For rationale, imagine a system that automatically causes a hardware trap if a pointer register is loaded with an address outside the valid address space

@M.M I would still like to know chapter and verse on this, if you could give it, because I know several systems that use it (e.g. during early boot).

C11 6.3.2.3/5 - the result of this conversion may be a trap representation (which is defined in 6.2.6.1/5)

@M.M Converting an integer to a pointer is not UB.  You only get UB if the conversion results in a trap representation and the lvalue where the result is stored is subsequently read.

@dbush The result is read (expression evaluated) by passing it to printf. Also the result of a cast is never an lvalue

@M.M The cast isn't an lvalue, but a parameter given to a function is (at least if it isn't a variadic parameter, if it is I'm not sure).

@M.M Ah, I get it now. The cases I had in mind were valid physical addresses for MMIO, mit arbitrary ones like here. Thanks for elaborating.

@DevSolar Could you edit your answer with this discussion in mind? I think this answers my question. Thanks, everyone.

@newbie: Well... nothing in this discussion answers anything in your question, actually. It might help if you would explain what you would have expected to happen. You're wandering into undefined behavior, but the results you're getting are readily explainable.

@newbie Wait... were you expecting a warning for the cast? In that case, know that C style casts ((typename)) are what C++ calls reinterpret_casts. There is no sanity check on either type, size, or content. Handle with care. ;-)

@DevSolar Yes, I was expecting a warning that turned into an error because of the flag -Werror. Thanks to all the comments here and in my question, I was able to understand the situation a bit better, but not fully. I had misconceptions about casting and assignments of pointers, although this part about UB escapes me, to be honest.

@newbie It's a corrolary, really. Obviously, "Hard-casting" some "random" integer value that isn't supposed to be a pointer into a pointer is desaster waiting to happen. M.M and I were discussing at which point exactly the deed were done -- at dereferencing ("using") the pointer (which your program doesn't do), or already at casting it and passing it to printf. If you are interested in the fine print there, post a new question (after checking that there isn't an answer on that already).
